# (Presto)Amazon Athena Convert String to Date

Tags: presto, amazon-athena

I would like to set the date to YYYYY-MM-01. How can I fix this error?
Please help me..

The error SQL:

```sql
select DATE_parse('2022-05-21','%Y-%m-01') as YYYYMM from tb1;
```

The error text :

> INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid format: "2022-05-21" is malformed at "21"

Comment: Why would you use `01` after `%Y-%m` instead of `%D`?

Comment: @KenWhite The reason is that I want to get the beginning of the month for the date in the column

Comment: If '2022-05-21' is entered, I want the value '2022-05-01'.

Answer (score 0):

Self resolved.
select DATE_ADD('day', 0, date_trunc('month', date(cast('2022-05-21' as date)))) from tb1;

Comment: Why do you need `date_add` here?

Comment: Because I wanted to change '2022-05-22' to '2022-05-01' using DATE_ADD.

Comment: But `date_trunc` is what does the changing and `date_add(.. 0)` does nothing, no?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select  cast(concat(substr('2022-05-21',1, 7), '-01') as date)
```